# Garbage Collection, .NET, C#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have three objects A, B and C. C is the child of both A and B. C has reference to A and B. A and B has reference to C.
I understand that when the reference to C from both A and B gets deleted, C becomes garbage and will be collected by GC.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. Should I set the Reference to A and B in C to NULL?
3. If Yes, What is the benefit?

```
public class A { public C Cr { get; set; } }
public class B { public C Cr { get; set; } }
public class C 

{
    public A Ar { get; set; }
    public B Br { get; set; }

}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oa = new A();
        var ob = new B();
        var oc = new C();

        oc.Ar = oa;
        oc.Br = ob;
        oa.Cr = oc;
        ob.Cr = oc;

        // Some operation

        oa.Cr = null;
        ob.Cr = null;

        //is the following code required?
        // if yes, what is the benefit?

        oc.Ar = null;
        oc.Br = null;

    }
```

Thanks

Ram

Comment: Please show *code* instead of describing things in relatively woolly terms. The concept of one object being the "child" of another isn't well-defined...

Comment: This makes no sense.  By "child of" do you mean inherits?  If so, then you can't inherit from more than one class in C#.  And if C inherits from B, then how in the hell does B inherit from C?  Does not compute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are no live references to C, then it becomes *eligible* for garbage collection. That doesn't mean it will be garbage collected straight away.

There's no need for you to set references to null within an object if that object is about to become eligible for garbage collection.

Note that if there are no "root" references to A, B or C, they will *all* be eligible for garbage collection, even if they continue to have references to each other.